# Relationship invoices between 5 tables

Tags: laravel

I have table called invoices, orders, games, products, users

This is my invoices table structure

```
id name order_id
```

This is my orders table structure

```
id name game_id product_id user_id
```

This is my games table structure

```
id name display_name
```

This is my products table structure

```
id product_sku name price profit
```

As you see in this case I'm trying to make an order that generate an invoices after you place an order. In the invoices, I wanted to show the games name, products name, price, and user who make the order.
What relationship should I use? is it hasMany, or belongsToMany? or should I make another table called invoice_order?

**Updated!**

I forgot to show my table game_product, I already make a belongsToMany relationship between games and products table.

```
id game_id product_id
```

Cmiiw

Comment: Shouldn't a game be related to a product?

Comment: Yes im using belongsToMany as games and product relationship

Comment: So basically a game can correspond to many products and a product can be many games?

Comment: Actually its game can correspond to many products and a product only has 1 game

Comment: Does each order row have to have a `game_id` or are there products which are not games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have the following table structure:

Orders (renamed from invoice)

```
id name user_id
```

order_product (pivot)

```
order_id product_id
```

games

```
id name display_name
```

products

```
id product_sku name price profit game_id
```

These should be the relationships:

Order model

```
public function products() { 
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}

public function user() { 
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Game model

```
public function product() { 
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
public function orders() { 
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Product::class);
}
```

Product model

```
public function game() { 
     return $this->belongsTo(Game::class);
}
public function orders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
}
```

This way you can generate an invoice:

```
$invoiceData = Order::with([ 'user', 'products', 'products.game' ])->find($id);
```

This will have all necessary information of the order within the `$invoiceData` object e.g. `$invoiceData->user` will be the user placing the order and `$invoiceData->products` will be a collection of ordered products.

Note that it's usually good practice to put the `price` in the `order_product` pivot as an extra pivot field since the price people buy an item for is not always the price that the item goes for at all times so that way you can have information on the price the item was sold for rather than what item was sold and how much it costs today.

Comment: I already have pivot game_product, can I still use it then? or should I re-create everything?

Comment: The hardest thing is every game has his own form, like 1 game should using user id and server id from its own game, and the other using username and game tag xD

Comment: the `game_product` pivot is not necessary because as you mentioned, each product corresponds to only 1 game so the relationship is stored on the `products` table.  For that part of the problem maybe you need multiple tables and some sort of [polymorphism](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: Btw @apokryfos, how to get the games display name using the $invoiceData?

Answer (score 0):

A simple belongs to relation is good enough for your case scenario

**Invoice.php**

```
public function order(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

**Order.php**

```
public function game(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Game::class)->select('id', 'name')
}
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class)->select('id', 'name')
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
Invoice::with(['order' => function($q) {
    return $q->with('game', 'product');
})->get();
```

Comment: So in this case my order hasOne games & product, because you can only select 1 game and 1 product to order, I wanted to show in the invoice what is the game name and what is the product, and also who make the order

Comment: That is why i have added belongsTo Relation as you can see in order with game and product relations picking up name for game and product is easy accessible. You will do something like `invoice->order->game->name` and `invoice->order->product->name`  in foreach loop

Comment: Wow I actually didnt know I can do that, I will try your answer later at home and I will inform you about the update! Thanks before syed!